# Displaying the contents according to their heading type

Tags: oracle, loops, cursor, procedure

```
I am new to SQL. My doubt is how to display the output inside the procedure like this.
I have various databases and its type and the current size all in one table 'predict_storage'
I want to display the output as:

    UAT:
        TMAP: 100G
        TCIG: 200G

    QA:
        QMAP: 100G
        QCIG: 200G

    DR:
        DRMAP: 100G
        DRCIG: 200G
```

Where UAT is the database type and TMAP, TCIG are databases and the current size is 100g. So I want the output to like this categorized based upon the database type.

Here is the code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test11 IS

        db_original_name_var varchar2(30);
        db_type varchar2(20);
        db_name varchar2(40);
        Used_space_var NUMBER;

        MAX_Used_space_monthvar NUMBER;
        RATE NUMBER;
        avg_space_future_min NUMBER;
        avg_space_future_max NUMBER;
        avgsp NUMBER;
        avg_space_3m NUMBER;
        avg_space_6m Number;
        avg_space_yr NUMBER;

        CURSOR db_list_cur is
        select original_db_name,database_type
        from database_list;

    Begin
      open db_list_cur;
      LOOP
      fetch db_list_cur
      into db_original_name_var,db_type;
     EXIT WHEN db_list_cur%NOTFOUND;

           select substr(avg(ave_used_space),0,6) INTO Used_space_var from month_space where db_original_name_var=database_name;
          select substr(max(ave_used_space),0,6) INTO MAX_Used_space_monthvar from month_space where db_original_name_var=database_name;

       --rate calc
     RATE := (MAX_Used_space_monthvar-Used_space_var)/Used_space_var;

     avg_space_future_max:=(Used_space_var)+(Used_space_var* RATE);
    avg_space_future_min:=(Used_space_var)-(Used_space_var* RATE);
    avgsp := (avg_space_future_max + avg_space_future_min)/2;

    avg_space_3m :=(avgsp)+(avgsp* rate* 3);
    avg_space_6m :=(avgsp)+(avgsp* rate* 6);
    avg_space_yr :=(avgsp)+(avgsp* rate* 12);

    insert into Predict_report
    (
    database_name ,
    Grwoth_rate ,
    Current_AVERAGE,
    Space_3mn,
    SPACE_6mn,
    Space_yr,
    database_type
    )
    values
    (
    db_original_name_var,
    RATE,
    round(avgsp,3),
    round(avg_space_3m,3),
    round(avg_space_6m,3),
    round(avg_space_yr,3),
    db_type
    );
    commit;

        loop
        dbms_output.put_line(db_type||':');
        select database_name into db_name from predict_report  where database_type=db_type;
        dbms_output.put_line(db_name);
        END LOOP;

       END LOOP;
       close db_list_cur;


    END;
    /
```

The tables I have are
    1) Storage Info

```
    DB_ID               NUMBER(38)
    DATABASE_NAME       VARCHAR2(50)
    DATABASE_SIZE       NUMBER
    TIME_STAMP          DATE
    FREE_SPACE          VARCHAR2(50)
    DATA_LINK_NAME      VARCHAR2(50)
    CUSTOMER_SPACE      NUMBER
    DATABASE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(30)
    USED_SPACE          NUMBER

2) Database_list

    DB_ID               NUMBER
    DB_NAME             VARCHAR2(50)
    DATALINK_NAME       VARCHAR2(50)
    DATABASE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20)
    ORIGINAL_DB_NAME    VARCHAR2(30)
```

3)Predict Report

```
    DATABASE_NAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
    GRWOTH_RATE         NUMBER
    CURRENT_AVERAGE     NUMBER
    SPACE_3MN           NUMBER
    SPACE_6MN           NUMBER
    SPACE_YR            NUMBER
    DATABASE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20)
```

4) Month_space

```
    DATABASE_NAME       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
    GRWOTH_RATE         NUMBER
    CURRENT_AVERAGE     NUMBER
    SPACE_3MN           NUMBER
    SPACE_6MN           NUMBER
    SPACE_YR            NUMBER
    DATABASE_TYPE       VARCHAR2(20)
```

-----The sql file is

```
        set echo off numf 999G999G999G999 lin 32000 trims on pages 50000 head on feed off     markup html off
    alter session set nls_numeric_characters='.''' nls_date_format='Day DD. Month, YYYY';
    spool /tmp/report.html
--prompt To: jialin.zhu@synchronoss.com
    prompt TO: varun.jain@synchronoss.com
    prompt cc: varun.jain@synchronoss.com
    prompt From: varun.jain@synchronoss.com
    prompt Subject: Daily space report
    prompt Content-type: text/html
    prompt MIME-Version: 1.0
    set markup html on entmap off table 'BORDER="2" BGCOLOR="white" FONTCOLOR="black"'
    prompt <i>Good morning, </i>
    prompt <i>Here is the Space report as on &_DATE</i>
    prompt <i>Kind Regards, </i>

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    prompt <br/><h3>Database Space Report</h3>

    set serveroutput on
    CLEAR COLUMNS
    Set HEADING ON
    Set COLSEP ,
    SET PAGESIZE 20000
    SET timing off feedback off verify off echo off

    prompt <br/><h3> Environment Space Summary</h3>
    column database_type heading 'Database Type'
    column Sum(current_average) format 9999 HEADING 'Total Space in GB'
    select database_type,Sum(current_average) from predict_report group by database_type;
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    prompt <br/><h3> DR database Summary</h3>
    COLUMN ('THETOTALSPACEINDRDATABASES:'||SUM(CURRENT_AVERAGE)||''||'GB') format 9999 heading     'total Space in DR database'
    select ('The total space in DR databases :' ||Sum(current_average)||' '||'GB') from     predict_report where DATABASE_TYPE not in ('UAT','QA');
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    prompt <br/><h3> databases  Summary</h3>
    column database_name format a30 heading ' DATABASE NAME'
    column round(GRWOTH_RATE*100,0)||'%'  heading 'GROWTH RATE'
    COLUMN CURRENT_AVERAGE FORMAT 9999 HEADING 'TODAYS SPACE in GB'
    COLUMN SPACE_3MN FORMAT 9999 HEADING 'SPACE AFT 3 MONTHS in GB'
    COLUMN SPACE_6MN FORMAT 9999 HEADING 'SPACE AFT 6 MONTHS in GB'
    COLUMN SPACE_YR FORMAT 9999 HEADING 'SPACE AFT A YEAR in GB'
    truncate table Predict_report;
    set serveroutput on
    exec report;
    SELECT         database_name,round(GRWOTH_RATE*100,0)||'%',current_average,space_3mn,space_6mn,space_yr     FROM Predict_report;

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    prompt <br/><h3>Database Space Summary</h3>
    column sum(current_average) FORMAT 9999 heading 'Total Space in GB'
    column sum(space_3mn) FORMAT 9999  heading 'Total Space in 3 months in GB'
    column sum(space_6mn) FORMAT 9999  heading 'Total Space in 6 months in GB'
    column sum(space_yr) FORMAT 9999 heading 'Total Space in 1 year in GB'
    select sum(current_average),sum(space_3mn),sum(space_6mn),sum(space_yr) from             Predict_report ;
    spool off;

---------to send the mail----------------

    host /usr/sbin/sendmail -t </tmp/report.html
```

and the output in the email received is like (It is in table form in the EMAIL)

```
DATABASE NAME   GROWTH RATE     TODAYS SPACE in GB  SPACE AFT 3 MONTHS in GB    SPACE AFT 6 MONTHS in GB    SPACE AFT A YEAR in GB 
CLNK    0%  199     200     200     202 
CCIG    0%  562     563     563     565 
DTXN    5%  330     377     424     518 
DCIG    0%  414     416     418     422 
QMAP    0%  16  16  17  17 
QLNP    0%  44  44  44  44 
QHTS    1%  32  32  33  34 
QFKP    1%  37  38  39  41 
QSAG    0%  168     169     170     172 
CSAG    0%  812     815     818     824 
LTATG   0%  25  25  25  25 
QCIG    0%  208     209     209     211 
TLNP    0%  341     341     341     341 
TMAP    0%  60  61  61  62 
TSAG    0%  223     226     228
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra loop you have now for output never terminates, so executing the procedure will appear to hang, at least until you run out of `dbms_output` buffer space; and doesn't retrieve the current value. And it's in the wrong place, as it will show data for all databases of that type each time round the loop, so you'll get duplicates (at best).

Although it doesn't seem to be a sensible way to do it, not least because you're assuming the procedure will always be run by something that can show the output and has the output enabled, you could do something like this, *after* `close db_list_cur`:

```
db_type := null;
for r in (select database_type, database_name, current_average
    from predict_report
    order by database_type, database_name)
loop
    if db_type is null or db_type != r.database_type then
        dbms_output.put_line(r.database_type || ':');
        db_type := r.database_type;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line(r.database_name ||' '||
        to_char(nvl(r.current_average, 0), '999990.00') ||'G');
end loop;
```

... or within the main loop based on the data you're inserting, rather than querying the table at the end (since they should match); but this will work whether you use your loops or a much simpler `insert into predict_report select ...`.

You don't need to use cursors to calculate the statistics or populate the table; you don't need PL/SQL at all really. You can just join the two tables together and work out the numbers from the returned values. Something like this would do it:

```
select database_name,
    rate as grwoth_rate,
    avg_used_space as current_average,
    avg_used_space + (avg_used_space * rate * 3) as space3mn,
    avg_used_space + (avg_used_space * rate * 6) as space6mn,
    avg_used_space + (avg_used_space * rate * 12) as spaceyr,
database_type
from (
    select database_name,
        database_type,
        avg_used_space,
        max_used_space,
        (max_used_space - avg_used_space)/avg_used_space as rate
    from (
        select dl.original_db_name as database_name,
            dl.database_type,
            trunc(avg(ave_used_space), 2) as avg_used_space,
            trunc(max(ave_used_space), 2) as max_used_space
        from database_list dl
        join month_space ms on ms.database_name = dl.original_db_name
        group by dl.original_db_name,
            dl.database_type
    )
);
```

You can use that to insert into the new table, though not sure you even need that really, if you're only producing output from within the procedure - not clear if that's the case, though you don't seem to want to show all the statistics you're calculating.

I'm also not sure your statistics make much sense though. You seem to be calculating a growth rate over an arbitrary number of months, and then predicting future sizes by applying that rate to the average over the life of the database rather than it's current size, which you don't seem to be collecting - you have the current average, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

But I am still wondering how to see the output in that format I mentioned above using a select statement outside the procedure? I removed that loop as it was not required and its working fine. I just need to find a way to use a select statement to display in above format.

Thank you

Comment: @user1554963 - the original question had the display inside the PL/SQL block, but... OK. A query doesn't really have any format, the client may choose to format it; so where will you be running the query? An SQL*Plus script? The three `db_type` sections has slightly different look in your question, I've edited it so the look the same, but don't know if that's what you actually want - can you update to show exactly what you need if not.

Comment: Thank you Alex.
I would be setting up a shell script for the sql file to spool the file into html body which is emailed every day to the whole database team using cronjob to report the database spaces. So the display from the procedure is not agreed upon, which is just genereal output in the email body where as the select statement gives proper output in the table format.
I l post the sql file above and also the sample output of the html

Comment: @user1554963 - I'm not sure I understand; what's wrong with the output you have now?

Comment: The procedure does not give the output in the table format in html in the email body. Its all in haphazard form just like text on each line which is not accepted by the department. They want it in the table form. Which only select statements are giving right now ,in html

Comment: @user1554963 - you want the HTML-formatted text to be produced from inside the procedure, to match the format you currently get from the plain SQL? Is there a reason you can't just keep using the plain SQL afterwards? (Also unsure why you `exec` your procedure mid-way through your script?)

Comment: Yes I need HTML format from the procedure as well and I also get it. But it does not match the format of the normal select statement which is tabular. A normal output is generated from procedures as I use DBMS_output... inside the procedure. I am executing 2 procedures first is storage info which inserts the daily space value in the tables and the second is report which generates the report and does calculations. I delete all the info from the report and re generate again so I exec the procedure before all the select statements.